# Returning a list of file metadata from GridFS - no Json deserializer

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, reactivemongo

This is a simple task with a maybe naive approach. Get all files that match a criteria.
With files I mean the file metadata - not the binary.

```
for {
    files <- gfs.find(BSONDocument("metadata.ideaId" -> BSONObjectID(ideaId))).collect[Seq]()
} yield {

    Ok(Json.toJson(files))
}
```

I have reactivemongo.api.gridfs.Implicits._ in scope but I get

```
No Json deserializer found for type Seq[reactivemongo.api.gridfs.ReadFile[reactivemongo.bson.BSONValue]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use very simple hand-made serializer for this task:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.Json._
import reactivemongo.api.gridfs.ReadFile
import reactivemongo.bson.{BSONValue, BSONObjectID}

implicit val fileWrites = new Writes[ReadFile[BSONValue]] {
  def writes(file: ReadFile[BSONValue]): JsValue = {
    val id = file.id.asInstanceOf[BSONObjectID].stringify
      obj(
        "_id" -> id, // need it with underscore
        "name" -> file.filename,
        "url" -> routes.Files.serveFile(id).url, // app specific
        "thumbnailUrl" -> routes.Files.serveFile(id).url, // app specific
        "extension" -> file.filename.split('.').last,
        "contentType" -> file.contentType,
        "size" -> file.length,
        "uploadDate" -> file.uploadDate,
        "deleteUrl" -> "", // app specific
        "deleteType" -> "DELETE"
    )
  }
}
```

so you can use it like this:

```
import helpers.Formats.fileWrites // your package here

def all = Action.async { request =
  gfs.find(query).collect[List]() map {
    case files: List[ReadFile[BSONValue]] => Ok(prettyPrint(obj("files" -> toJson(files))))
}
```

Comment: I'm sure this works. Meanwhile I did a quick and dirty workaround to access the fs.files collection directly and query it like a regular collection.

Comment: @DanielKhan just to be sure: you're using ReactiveMongo with play plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You try to serialize 'files' which is a Seq[reactivemongo.api.gridfs.ReadFile[reactivemongo.bson.BSONValue]] to JSON which is not possible out of the box. You have to provide an implicit JSON serializer (as an instance of play.api.libs.json.Writes[Seq[ReadFile[BSONValue]]]) for it.

See http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/ScalaJson

There is a section 'Converting a Scala value to JsValue' which describes the details.

Comment: I thought that ReactiveMongo also contains the implicits inside http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.9/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.gridfs.Implicits$

The source also looks as if it should work.

Comment: As you may notice from the comment in the sources this is a /** A default `BSONReader` for `ReadFile`. */. What you need is a play.api.libs.json.Writes[Seq[ReadFile[BSONValue]]]).